# Stale NFS handle, but nothing is mounted

Tags: nfs, network-share, mount

I have an nfs server (192.168.1.180) that is sharing a directory to my rapsberry pi (192.168.1.32). I have had this working before.

Recently, the server went down - but not the client. After realizing what happened, I force-unmounted the client mountpoint and tried to remount. Now I'm getting a bunch of stale NFS file handle errors.

Here's the command I'm running:

```
xbian@xbian /etc/init.d $ sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.1.180:/mnt/media /media
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Feb 19 21:00:00 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.180,clientaddr=192.168.1.32'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Stale NFS file handle
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.180,clientaddr=192.168.1.32'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Stale NFS file handle
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.180,clientaddr=192.168.1.32'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Stale NFS file handle
```

- The mountpoint is NOT in fstab
- I have restarted the server's nfs-common service
- I have expressly unshared the directory to the raspberry pi, restarted, reshared

I'm at a loss here. I can't seem to mount my nfs share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more trial and error, I found that running `exportfs -f` on the server actually worked. I was able to mount after that.

Comment: Glad it helped someone else!